# OpenVPN: The VPN connection to ... because of invalid VPN secrets

Tags: vpn, ethernet, openvpn, keyrings

I am 3 days into using Linux. I set up an OpenVPN connection following the instructions set out by: https://www.goldenfrog.com/support/vyprvpn/vpn-setup/linux/openvpn

OpenVPN installation went smoothly. The problem arose when I tried to connect. After setting up the connection:

1. I went to the connections are and selected my VPN.
2. The error message I get is
   `The VPN connection to "My VPN" because of invalid VPN secrets.`
3. There are no additional prompt or areas to input commands. The dialog box disappears after sometime.

Now my computer is ancient (the reason I installed ubuntu at first) so I don't have a wireless adapter. I'm connecting via an ethernet cable but I notice that the VPN connection when it is attempting a connection looks like its attempting to connect to the VPN over Wi-Fi. The connected symbol changes from 2 arrows in opposite directions to the Wi-Fi symbol.

Other than that I'm not quite sure what else could be causing it. I've read that the problem lies with keyring issues but I don't get any prompts to access my keyring so it looks like the solution has to be in the initial set up.

How can I solve the VPN secrets error on 14.04 when connecting to the internet via an ethernet cable?

Comment: The animated wifi icon is the default "connecting to" behavior for any connection, whether it be wired, wireless, or VPN. The "invalid VPN secrets" suggests an incorrect password, so double check you typed it correctly. Also try [the steps in the second half of this page](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/ubuntu-tiphow-to-connectdisconnect-vpn-from-the-command-line.html) to see if its a problem with keyrings.

Comment: Ok brilliant I'll give it a shot. The binary file can't be opened with a GUI. Can you provide the terminal commands to get root access and edit lines in the binary file from terminal. Or is there a way of getting root access via one of the graphical apps. gedit and Ghex seem to be the top choices but they don't have permissions to open the bin file

Comment: From the command line you can promote a GUI program, for example gedit, with `gksudo gedit` which will then prompt you for your sudo password. Or you can edit it directly from the command line using the nano editor with `sudo nano /path/to/file`; once you make the edits, save is Ctrl+O followed by Enter to confirm the overwrite and Ctrl+X to exit.

Comment: Have you set a crt file. Under VPN settings you may need a certificate from your vpn server. You can usually download them from your provider.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really that this is a bug really. 
Considering that it works for a majority of users 
Using openVPN and network manager.

Do you have the proper permissions of the key and certificate file?
What happens if you run

```
openvpn --config nameofyourconfigfile.conf
```

as **root** from the terminal?
please paste the output here if it does not work. It should provide more debug information.

If it does work like that. Then you have permission problems on your key and or certificate file.

Answer (score 1):

I've used `openvpn` successfully many times with it's companion, `vpnc-scripts`.

Once both of these packages are available, try connecting with the following:

1. `openconnect -b -u USER.NAME --force-dpd 60 --authgroup=default --script=/usr/share/vpnc-scripts/vpnc-script VPN.DOMAIN.TLD`

This should also set up your routes correctly so that once you do successfully connect to the VPN, your computer will know how to communicate with the machines found there.

#### WARNING

When connected to a VPN using `vpnc-scripts` default script as described, your computer will resolve all DNS queries using the DNS server provided by the VPN.  This means that, when you go to Facebook.com, the VPN DNS server will respond, instead of your normally used server.

Answer (score 0):

This was probably identified as confirmed bug.
See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-openvpn/+bug/738849

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me constantly.

The VPN works fine the first time, and fails with this message any other time.

I use this workaround:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

And then try to connect again, and it works.